# sl-vue-tree + vue-cli3.1 on ie11

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babel-polyfill

I am Japanese and I am not good at English sorry.

I am using vue-cli3.1.

I want to use this module on ie11.
https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree

It says you can use on ie11 with babel-polyfil.

But I can'y use babel-polyfil correctly.

I did "yarn add @babel/polyfill".

And at the top of the main.ts I imported it.

But it did't work.

```
import "@babel/polyfill"

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

---

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <SlVueTree v-model="treeModel">

    </SlVueTree>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

//sl-vue-tree
import SlVueTree from "sl-vue-tree-original";


@Component({
  components: {
    SlVueTree
  }
})
export default class About extends Vue {

  public treeModel = [
    {
        "title": "Item1",
        "isLeaf": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Item2",
        "isLeaf": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Folder1",
        "isExpanded": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "Item3",
                "isLeaf": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Item4",
                "isLeaf": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Folder2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Item5",
                        "isLeaf": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "isSelected": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Item6",
        "isLeaf": true
    }
];

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you use webpack with babel-loader? If so, what does your config look like?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. How do I know that?

Comment: You can find it by checking your build script (probably in package.json). Does it include webpack? Otherwise check if there's a webpack.config.js or similar file in the frontend folder. This doesn't work if you're using something similar to Create-React-App but I'm not too familiar with vue.js to know if there's anything similar for that 涙

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. Im using Vue cli 3.6 and sl-vue-tree 1.8.4

Add transpileDependencies to vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 transpileDependencies: ['sl-vue-tree'],
 ...
}
```

My babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 presets: [
  ["@vue/app", {
    modules: "commonjs"
  }]
 ]
};
```

In my vue component im just importing sl-vue-tree like this:

```
import slVueTree from "sl-vue-tree";
```